# Android NDK-C: stddef.h:212:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'

Tags: c, android-ndk

I am trying to crosscompile some stuff for android and I am getting the following....

```
In file included from /Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:50:0,
             from ./src/z_zone.h:52,
             from ./src/doomdef.h:49,
             from ./src/d_items.h:38,
             from ./src/d_player.h:43,
             from ./src/doomstat.h:43,
             from ./src/am_map.c:39:
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include/stddef.h:212:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include/stddef.h:212:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
In file included from /Users/jackiegleason/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:55:0,
             from ./src/z_zone.h:52,
             from ./src/doomdef.h:49,
             from ./src/d_items.h:38,
             from ./src/d_player.h:43,
             from ./src/doomstat.h:43,
             from ./src/am_map.c:39:
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:59:30: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:59:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:101:33: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
/Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:101:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

Do I need to configure differently or something?

**Update**

One thing I did notice is that it is using....

> /Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6...

When I am using a standalone toolchain...

```
echo $PATH
/Users/me/toolchain/bin
```

From the output...

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
  If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Also noticed this in the configure....

```
# FIXME: To remove some day.
if test "x$host_alias" != x; then
if test "x$build_alias" = x; then
  cross_compiling=maybe
  echo "$as_me: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
  If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used." >&2
  elif test "x$build_alias" != "x$host_alias"; then
    cross_compiling=yes
  fi
fi
```

I of course can hack this so cross compile is always yes, this lets it work with....

```
checking build system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I think we need to see the file /Users/me/Development/Android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include/stddef.h

Comment: This is standard and available from the Android SRC but I don't think this is the issue. Besides "mac" shouldn't matter this is a cross compile. Because this is a native Android lib (IE probably used by a host of other apps) I doubt that is the issue. If you really want I can link to it though

Comment: Did you perhaps let an autoconfigure script for the project run against your development machine's environment?  That would probably create interesting failures like this.  If you have to run an autoconfigure against a surrogate environment, try a linux VM but you may still have to make manual changes.

Comment: I don't believe I did, I can provide my script to call the configure script but I am pretty sure it ran as arm (host was defined). Would posting the script help?

Comment: Actually maybe you are on to something... ./script.sh: line 3:  : command not found
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0

Comment: I think commenting out this in my config.h fixed it... /* Define to `unsigned int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
/* #define size_t unsigned int */ will make answer after I confirm. If someone can give a better answer as to why this happens go for it and I will give you the flag.